if the sequents (Γ ⊢ ψ) and (∆ ⊢ ψ) are both correct, then so is the sequent ((Γ ∩ ∆) ⊢ ψ)
This comes from Chriswell mathematical logic. It is not so clear to me. It's stating that if ψ is provable from assumptions in Γ and also from assumptions in ∆, it is provable from the intersection of the assumptions in Γ and ∆.
But since there can be different proofs of a statement it could be that ψ comes from assumptions that are not in that intersection.
Am I missing something?

You'd have to be more precise about the logic being used. For example, with $\Gamma = {A}, \Delta = {B}$, you have both $\Gamma \vdash A \lor B$ and $\Delta \vdash A \lor B$, but $\Gamma \cap \Delta = {} \nvdash A \lor B$. EDIT: ah, the solution is simply that the statement is false.

@NaïmFavier Indeed, thanks for spotting my mistake!

The claim is false. Take $\psi = \lnot X \lor X$,  $\Delta = {\psi}$ and $\Gamma = {\lnot X \leftrightarrow X}$. Clearly, $\Gamma \cap \Delta = \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \not\vdash \psi$, but $\Gamma \vdash \psi$ and $\Delta \vdash \psi$.

Thanks everybody!
